# Very harsh shading part of the model

Tags: faces, topology, shadows

I am getting strange hard shading on a part of my model with point light on current specific position in material mode (Blender internal). I've tried recalculating normals, also they are all pointing in right direction. Can anyone notice a problem in my topology which could cause such harsh shading from one point forward? I would be really grateful for any clues.

Model file
[image]

[image: Part with strange shading]

[image: Topology]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

There is nothing wrong. Also consider switching to EEVEE or Cycles with a denoiser like Intel Open Image Denoiser, Optix Denoiser or internal one.

This you can get by tweaking some values:
[image]
Materiel view
[image]
Render

[image]

Comment: I must stay in blender internal, because I will use model in a game engine. That shadow is showing very harsh there, when i set light to similar position. How could i make it at least a little more gradienty (if that makes sense)?

Comment: @tomazj There is nothing you can do. Blender Internal does not have a bounce lighting so if you use Material Preview it is no more than what Internal itself can do. You need to fake bounce lighting with AO, Environment Light or lamps.

Comment: @tomazj And what Blender viewport renderer has to do with a model for a game engine? Do you use BGE? Any way EEVEE is much closer to how a modern game engine will draw your model. And if you need a preview of how it will look like in Unreal or Unity you should use Blender 2.8 with EEVEE.